# How do I group records that are within a specific time interval using Spark Scala or sql?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I would like to group records in scala only if they have the same ID and their time is within 1 min of each other.

I am thinking conceptually something like this? But I am not really sure

```
HAVING a.ID = b.ID AND a.time + 30 sec > b.time AND a.time - 30 sec < b.time




| ID         |     volume  |           Time             |
|:-----------|------------:|:--------------------------:|
| 1          |      10     |    2019-02-17T12:00:34Z    |
| 2          |      20     |    2019-02-17T11:10:46Z    |
| 3          |      30     |    2019-02-17T13:23:34Z    |
| 1          |      40     |    2019-02-17T12:01:02Z    |
| 2          |      50     |    2019-02-17T11:10:30Z    |
| 1          |      60     |    2019-02-17T12:01:57Z    |
```

to this:

```
| ID         |     volume  | 
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |      50     |   // (10+40)
| 2          |      70     |   // (20+50)
| 3          |      30     |


df.groupBy($"ID", window($"Time", "1 minutes")).sum("volume")
```

the code above is 1 solution but it always rounds.

For example 2019-02-17T12:00:45Z will have a range of

```
2019-02-17T12:00:00Z TO 2019-02-17T12:01:00Z.
```

I am looking for this instead:
`2019-02-17T11:45:00Z TO 2019-02-17T12:01:45Z.`

Is there a way?

Comment: `12:00:34` and `12:01:02` are within one minute of each other.  But `12:01:02` and `12:01:57` are also within one minute of each other.  Why didn't you want to combine all three?  And why do you prefer to combine the first two rather than the last two?

Comment: Should your final `2019-02-17T11:45:00Z TO 2019-02-17T12:01:45Z.` read as `2019-02-17T12:01:45Z TO 2019-02-17T12:01:45Z`?

Comment: 12:00:34 and 12:01:02 are within 1 min. But 12:00:34 and 12:01:57 are not. I wouldn't want to combine them they are almost 2 min a part. I hope that clarifies. 2019-02-17T11:45:00Z (+1m) <2019-02-17T12:00:45Z> (+1m) 2019-02-17T12:01:45Z

Comment: No, you ignored half my question.  Why are you not combining `12:01:02` and `12:01:57`?  They're 55 seconds apart.  Is it that you don't want to combine them because `12:01:02` is already being combined with `12:00:34`?  In which case, if there was a row for `12:00:01` as well, things would change.  You'd combine `12:00:01` and `12:00:34`, and separately combine `12:01:02` and `12:01:57`.  That would mean that you can't tell which rows to combine without going back to the start of the sequence and rolling forwards.  That's a sequential loop, something you don't do in SQL.

Comment: Keep in mind they also have to have the same ID in order to combine. But yes 12:01:02 and 12:01:57 wold be combined because they are within 1 min, so is 12:00:34 and 12:01:02, but 12:00:34 and 12:01:57 would not be combine.

Comment: You want to combine `12:00:34` with `12:01:02` ***and*** you want to combine `12:01:02` with `12:01:57`? That would duplicate the midle of the three values...

Comment: you are right... it would.  Maybe it is better to just have a set bucket then, not a dynamic one. I didn't think about it but it would create duplicates

Comment: Bucketing is simpler to code and cheaper for the machine to perform.  Whether or not it's suitable depends on what you're using it for.  If you need dynamic behaviour, you need a loop and operate on it very sequentially.

Comment: you are correct! thanks again for sticking with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.sql.functions` provides overloaded window functions as below.

**1. window(timeColumn: Column, windowDuration: String) :** Generates tumbling time windows given a timestamp specifying column. Window starts are inclusive but the window ends are exclusive, e.g. 12:05 will be in the window [12:05,12:10) but not in [12:00,12:05).

The windows will look like:

```
  {{{
    09:00:00-09:01:00
    09:01:00-09:02:00
    09:02:00-09:03:00 ...
  }}}
```

**2. window((timeColumn: Column, windowDuration: String, slideDuration: String):** 
          Bucketize rows into one or more time windows given a timestamp specifying column. Window starts are inclusive but the window ends are exclusive, e.g. 12:05 will be in the window [12:05,12:10) but not in [12:00,12:05).
    **slideDuration** Parameter specifying the sliding interval of the window, e.g. `1 minute`.A new window will be generated every `slideDuration`. Must be less than or equal to the `windowDuration`.

The windows will look like:

```
{{{
  09:00:00-09:01:00
  09:00:10-09:01:10
  09:00:20-09:01:20 ...
}}}
```

**3. window((timeColumn: Column, windowDuration: String, slideDuration: String, startTime: String):**  Bucketize rows into one or more time windows given a timestamp specifying column. Window starts are inclusive but the window ends are exclusive, e.g. 12:05 will be in the window [12:05,12:10) but not in [12:00,12:05).

The windows will look like:

```
{{{
  09:00:05-09:01:05
  09:00:15-09:01:15
  09:00:25-09:01:25 ...
}}}
```

For example, in order to have hourly tumbling windows that start 15 minutes past the hour, e.g. 12:15-13:15, 13:15-14:15... provide `startTime` as `15 minutes`. **This is the perfect overloaded window function which suites your requirement.**

Please find working code as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkWindowTest extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("File_Streaming")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  //Prepare Test Data
  val df = Seq((1, 10, "2019-02-17 12:00:49"), (2, 20, "2019-02-17 11:10:46"),
    (3, 30, "2019-02-17 13:23:34"),(2, 50, "2019-02-17 11:10:30"),
    (1, 40, "2019-02-17 12:01:02"), (1, 60, "2019-02-17 12:01:57"))
    .toDF("ID", "Volume", "TimeString")

  df.show()
  df.printSchema()

+---+------+-------------------+
| ID|Volume|         TimeString|
+---+------+-------------------+
|  1|    10|2019-02-17 12:00:49|
|  2|    20|2019-02-17 11:10:46|
|  3|    30|2019-02-17 13:23:34|
|  2|    50|2019-02-17 11:10:30|
|  1|    40|2019-02-17 12:01:02|
|  1|    60|2019-02-17 12:01:57|
+---+------+-------------------+

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Volume: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- TimeString: string (nullable = true)

  //Converted String Timestamp into Timestamp
  val modifiedDF = df.withColumn("Time", to_timestamp($"TimeString"))

  //Dropped String Timestamp from DF
  val modifiedDF1 = modifiedDF.drop("TimeString")

  modifiedDF.show(false)
  modifiedDF.printSchema()

+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ID |Volume|TimeString         |Time               |
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1  |10    |2019-02-17 12:00:49|2019-02-17 12:00:49|
|2  |20    |2019-02-17 11:10:46|2019-02-17 11:10:46|
|3  |30    |2019-02-17 13:23:34|2019-02-17 13:23:34|
|2  |50    |2019-02-17 11:10:30|2019-02-17 11:10:30|
|1  |40    |2019-02-17 12:01:02|2019-02-17 12:01:02|
|1  |60    |2019-02-17 12:01:57|2019-02-17 12:01:57|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Volume: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- TimeString: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Time: timestamp (nullable = true)

  modifiedDF1.show(false)
  modifiedDF1.printSchema()

+---+------+-------------------+
|ID |Volume|Time               |
+---+------+-------------------+
|1  |10    |2019-02-17 12:00:49|
|2  |20    |2019-02-17 11:10:46|
|3  |30    |2019-02-17 13:23:34|
|2  |50    |2019-02-17 11:10:30|
|1  |40    |2019-02-17 12:01:02|
|1  |60    |2019-02-17 12:01:57|
+---+------+-------------------+

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Volume: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Time: timestamp (nullable = true)

  //Main logic
  val modifiedDF2 = modifiedDF1.groupBy($"ID", window($"Time", "1 minutes","1 minutes","45 seconds")).sum("Volume")

  //Renamed all columns of DF.
  val newNames = Seq("ID", "WINDOW", "VOLUME")
  val finalDF = modifiedDF2.toDF(newNames: _*)

  finalDF.show(false)

+---+---------------------------------------------+------+
|ID |WINDOW                                       |VOLUME|
+---+---------------------------------------------+------+
|2  |[2019-02-17 11:09:45.0,2019-02-17 11:10:45.0]|50    |
|1  |[2019-02-17 12:01:45.0,2019-02-17 12:02:45.0]|60    |
|1  |[2019-02-17 12:00:45.0,2019-02-17 12:01:45.0]|50    |
|3  |[2019-02-17 13:22:45.0,2019-02-17 13:23:45.0]|30    |
|2  |[2019-02-17 11:10:45.0,2019-02-17 11:11:45.0]|20    |
+---+---------------------------------------------+------+

}
```

Comment: Your first test data record is incorrect.  It should be `12:00:34` rather than `12:00:49`.  That will alter the results.  The OP doesn't want regular 1 minute intervals from the 45second mark.  The OP wants dynamic windows based on the data.  So, for ID=1 that would be `12:00:34 -> 12:01:34` and then `12:01:57 -> 12:02:57`, but not `12:01:02 -> 12:02:02`, because it's starting record is contained in the first window.  Which is significantly more laborious to achieve *(you **must** go to the very start of the sequence and iterate forwards, which all SQL sucks at)*

Comment: Great answer! thank you for all the information, it would be nice if there was a way to make the "startTime" dynamic? instead of every 45 sec mark. The program would take the record time and just add 30 sec each way

Comment: startTime can be dynamic. Instead of hard coding it 45 you can pass it as a parameter.

Comment: e.d. $"time" like that? dynamic in a sense of the time of the record, not a generic time

Comment: so if a record is 12:01:20. the range will be 12:00:20 <-> 12:02:20

Comment: @KZapagol - To make it easier to explain, I'll use integers.  For the sequence `3, 6, 10, 11` with a "window size" of `4`, the windows would be `[3 -> 7), [10 -> 14)` and NOT `[3 -> 7), [7 -> 11), [11 -> 15)`. Because the ideal situation for the OP is to start the new bucket from the next record after the current bucket ends, not the end of the current bucket.